# x path and xml with many xml namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath

This may be simple but I am struggling to prepare correct x-path.

my XML looks like below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<POSLog xmlns="URI-A" xmlns:SES="URI-B" xmlns:SES_DATA="URI-C" xmlns:IXR_DATA="URI-D" xmlns:CST="URI-E">
    <Transaction MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0" FixVersion="0" SES:InternalMajorVersion="2" SES:InternalMinorVersion="3" SES:InternalFixVersion="11" CancelFlag="false" TrainingModeFlag="false">
        <RetailStoreID>0000000138</RetailStoreID>
```

I use x-path //ns0:POSLog/Transaction/RetailStoreID to get the value 0000000138
but its not giving any results in Java based application.

Comment: Have you tried URI-A:POSLog/… instead of ns0, too?

Comment: All your XML elements are bound to a default namespace: `xmlns="URI-A"`. How do you call the XPath expression? What environment, what language?

Comment: Java based application. SAP PI

Comment: @Hermann12 I tried it now but no success.